# Integration of PHP-Python applications

Tags: php, python, web-services, integration

I would like to integrate a Python application and PHP application for data access. I have a Python app and it stores data in its application, now i want to access the data from python database to php application database. For PHP-Python integration which methods are used?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have two separate apps, with separate databases, or do you have a Python script whose functions/logic you'd like to use in your PHP app?

Comment: Have separate apps and database.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to build a private API for your PHP app to access your Python app. For example, if using Django, make a page that takes several parameters and returns JSON-encoded information. Load that into your PHP page, use `json_decode`, and you're all set.